# Limit the number of nested directories traversed by os.walk

Tags: python, html-parsing, os.walk

I'm using Python to parse a WordPress site downloaded via wget. All the HTML files are nested inside a complicated folder structure (thanks to WordPress and its long URLs), like `site_dump/2010/03/11/post-title/index.html`.

However, within the `post-title` directory there are other directories for the feed and for Google News-esque number-based indexes:

```
site_dump/2010/03/11/post-title/index.html  # I want this
site_dump/2010/03/11/post-title/feed/index.html  # Not these
site_dump/2010/03/11/post-title/115232/site.com/2010/03/11/post-title/index.html
```

I only want to access the index.html files that are at the 5th nested level (`site_dump/2010/03/11/post-title/index.html`), and not beyond. Right now I split the `root` variable by a slash (`/`) in the `os.walk` loop and only deal with the file if it is inside 5 levels of folders:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('site_dump'):
  nested_levels = root.split('/')
  if len(nested_levels) == 5:
    print(nested_levels)  # Eventually do stuff with the file here
```

However, this seems kind of inefficient, since `os.walk` is still traversing those really deep folders. Is there a way to limit how deep `os.walk` goes when traversing a directory tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify dirs in place to prevent further traversal into the directory structure.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('site_dump'):
  nested_levels = root.split('/')
  if len(nested_levels) == 5:
    del dirs[:]
    # Eventually do stuff with the file here
```

`del dirs[:]` will remove the contents of the list, rather than replace dirs with a reference to a new list. When doing this it is important to modify the list *in-place*.

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk), with `topdown` referring to an optional parameter for `os.walk` that you omitted and defaults to `True`:

> When topdown is True, the caller can modify the dirnames list in-place
>   (perhaps using del or slice assignment), and walk() will only recurse
>   into the subdirectories whose names remain in dirnames; this can be
>   used to prune the search, impose a specific order of visiting, or even
>   to inform walk() about directories the caller creates or renames
>   before it resumes walk() again. Modifying dirnames when topdown is
>   False is ineffective, because in bottom-up mode the directories in
>   dirnames are generated before dirpath itself is generated.